# Detect Chrome restart from client javascript

Tags: javascript, web-applications

How can I detect client-side whether a user has just re-opened chrome with "Continue where I left off" enabled?

I would like modify client-side behavior based upon whether the user has **just** come from a related page. Re-opening the browser should not activate this behavior, but `document.referrer` is preserved.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Cookies.
The cookies are stored in the client side and they can be seted and retrived via javascript (if the browser configuration allows it). Here you have examples for setting ang getting cookies with javascript.

```
function setCookie(c_name,value,exdays)
{
    var exdate=new Date();
    exdate.setDate(exdate.getDate() + exdays);
    var c_value=escape(value) + ((exdays==null) ? "" : "; expires="+exdate.toUTCString());
    document.cookie=c_name + "=" + c_value;  /*  In this line you set the value */
}

function getCookie(c_name)
{
var c_value = document.cookie;
var c_start = c_value.indexOf(" " + c_name + "=");
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf(c_name + "=");  /* In this line you get the key */
  }
if (c_start == -1)
  {
  c_value = null;
  }
else
  {
  c_start = c_value.indexOf("=", c_start) + 1;
  var c_end = c_value.indexOf(";", c_start);
  if (c_end == -1)
  {
c_end = c_value.length;
}
c_value = unescape(c_value.substring(c_start,c_end));  /* In this line you get the value */
}
return c_value;
}
```

You can get more information here: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: No, this does not work. See [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=128513) (same problem/feature with Chrome). With "Continue where I left off", session cookies **not** deleted on browser restart. Same goes for sessionStorage.